# How to use tabs for all indentation in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation, webstorm

I'm trying to make an indentation scheme for IntelliJ where no spaces are used for indentation of HTML files. I've checked "use tab character" both for default code style and for HTML in particular. However, some spaces are still used as seen in the screenshot below, such as for the head and body tags, and the div tag with ID "top".

I've tried all settings I could think of, but I can't get these spaces to become tabs. Anyone know how?

Thanks!

[image: How?]

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution as it turns out! Just set the value in the "Indent" box to the same as tab size, like this:
[image: Solution]